# node-exif: No gps data?

Tags: node.js, exif

I'm using node-exif to retrieve the metadata of images taken with my iphone. Lots of data is extracted, but GPS data is missing. Apple Photos app for Mac shows the image position. So I guess the data is anywhere.

```
var ExifImage = require('exif').ExifImage
try {
    new ExifImage({image: 'test.jpg'}, (err, data) => {
        console.log(data)
    })
} catch(e) {
    console.log('Error when trying to retrieve exif data.')
}
```

In the output the GPS property is empty.

> ...,   gps: {},   interoperability: {},   makernote: { error: 'Unable to extract
>   Makernote information as it is in an unsupported or unrecognized
>   format.' } }

The given error in the makernote property seems not relevant since exif does not throw an error an `err` in the callback is `false`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is related to the Mac OS Photos app. Usually relevant metadata is stripped when exporting (e.g. dragging out of the app window). Use the build in export feature and check "location data" and the image will be exported including the location data (see File > Export ...).